# Bulk delete in Entity framework using Entity Sql

Tags: entity-framework-5

I want to implement bulk delete in Entity framework. I am planning to use Entity sql for that, but after a long search i am not able to find a single example of delete statement in Entity Sql. I dont want to use Sql statement also. Does Entity framework provide any bulk update without using For each loop internally ? I want to delete complete list of object in single transaction. Is it possible in Entity Sql ?

Comment: ESql does not support CUD operations - only queries are supported.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended) that provides bulk delete/update that I know of.

Most people using entity framework do not use this because it bypasses any logic built in the model (no code executed in the savechanges override for example), but if you are only doing data retrieval/delete without any business logic this might help.